How to solve definite integral where the independent variable is in division and a trig function?
Okay, so this is a messy equation, and I don't like it, but I need it, so I really appreciate the people helping me solve this, thanks.
I need to integrate this mess from time = $0$ to time = $t_{max}$
$$\int_0^{t_{max}} \left(V_t \cdot\frac{ V_0 - V_t \cdot \tan(\frac{gt}{V_t})}{V_t + V_0 \cdot \tan(\frac{gt}{V_t})}\right)^2  \; k \; dt$$
Time (t) is the independent variable and everything else ($V_0$, $V_t$, $g$ is gravity, $k$, $t_{max}$) is a constant
I am a high school student taking calculus and so far, all I know the conceptual part and the power rule and that is about it. For everything else I use an equation sheet and I know that division and trig add layers of complexity into the mix when solving integrals, so I don't know how to start. Plus, the variable is in the numerator and denominator so that makes it more complicated. Any advice on the steps I should follow?
By the way $V_t$ doesn't have anything to do with time, it is just bad naming on my part.

Are my eyes failing me or is the entire inside of the integral independent of $t$?
I'm assuming that $V_t$ is supposed to be dependent on $t$?

My bad, you're right

Assuming that $V_\cdot$'s are velocities, your integrand does not make dimensional sense. Why are you subtracting $V_t \tan \left( \frac{g t}{V_t} \right)$, which has dimensions of velocity, from $V_t V_0$, which has dimensions of velocity squared?

It looks strange but it works out. The fraction inside the squared exponent is the velocity function for time. Drag force is dependent on some constant $k$ times $v^2$ at any time $t$, and the integral of force $dt$ is impulse which is what I am trying to find with this equation. $V_t$ is just terminal velocity and $V_0$ is initial velocity.

I see. That much makes sense to me: the term in parentheses is a velocity, which is then squared. But should the second term in the numerator have another velocity multiplied in? E.g., is it maybe $V_0 V_t \tan \left( \frac{g t}{V_t} \right)$, or $V_t^2 \tan \left( \frac{g t}{V_t} \right)$? Not that it matters for solving the integral, but it's probably good to check.

You can minorly simplify things (and perhaps gain some physical intuition about the problem) by working with non-dimensional terms. We have a non-dimensional time $\frac{g t}{V_t}$, which we'll call $T$. Also, let $T_\max = \frac{g t_\max}{V_t}$. Then observe that $d t = \frac{V_t}{g} d T$. The integral now becomes
$$\left( \frac{k V_t^3}{g} \right) \underbrace{\int_0^{T_\max} \left( \frac{1 - \frac{V_t}{V_0} \tan T}{\frac{V_t}{V_0} + \tan T} \right)^2 d T}_I$$
You can verify that the integral $I$ is now dimensionless, and the dimensional part is a momentum (impulse).
To keep notation simple, let's denote $x = \frac{V_t}{V_0}$, a non-dimensional parameter. Then
$$I = \int_0^{T_\max} \left( \frac{1 - x \tan T}{x + \tan T} \right)^2 d T$$
We are looking to make the substitution $u = \tan T$. To do so, we note that $d u = \sec^2 T d T$. So, let's multiply the numerator and denominator by $\sec^2 T = 1 + \tan^2 T$:
$$I = \int_0^{T_\max} \frac{(1 - x \tan T)^2}{(1 + \tan^2 T) (x + \tan T)^2} \sec^2 T d T$$
Making the substitution, we obtain
$$I = \int_0^{\tan T_\max} \frac{(1 - x u)^2}{(1 + u^2) (x + u)^2} d u$$
This is a rather easy partial fraction decomposition:
$$I = \int_0^{\tan T_\max} \left( \frac{x^2 + 1}{(x + u)^2} - \frac{1}{1 + u^2} \right) d u = \left[ -\frac{x^2 + 1}{x + u} - \tan^{-1} u \right]_0^{\tan T_\max}$$
Keeping in mind that $u = \tan T$, then $\tan^{-1} u = T$, so that we may write
$$I = \left[ -\frac{x^2 + 1}{x + \tan T_\max} - T_\max \right] - \left[ -\frac{x^2 + 1}{x} \right] = \frac{(x^2 + 1) \tan T_\max}{x (x + \tan T_\max)} - T_\max$$
So, putting everything together (including the substitutions for $T_\max$ and $x$), your integral evaluates to
$$\boxed{\left( \frac{k V_t^3}{g} \right) \left[ \frac{\left( \left( \frac{V_t}{V_0} \right)^2 + 1 \right) \tan \left( \frac{g t_\max}{V_t} \right)}{\left( \frac{V_t}{V_0} \right) \left( \frac{V_t}{V_0} + \tan \left( \frac{g t_\max}{V_t} \right) \right)} - \frac{g t_\max}{V_t} \right]}$$

I just realized, you are right, I fixed the equation so that $V_t$ multiplies the whole numerator, not just a part of it. I used a converter to turn the formula into mathjax from my text editor and did not spot the error.

Perfect. This might allow some simplification in the result. I'll update my answer.

Thank you so much!

@FrontiersAerospace No problem! Glad to help.
